# Почему не отрабатывает юнит?

Tags: linux, debian, демон

Создал юнит `wentilation.service` со следующим кодом:

```
[Unit]
Description = Run Wentilation system :3

[Servise]
RemainAflerExit=true
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/kononov/initialization1/script_run

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Скрипт `script_run` выглядит так:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ./program
```

В bash ввёл:

```
sudo systemctl enable wentilation 
sudo systemctl start wentilation
```

Ошибок не дал, но и по существу не заработал. Перезагрузил компьютер и ввёл:

```
sudo systemctl status wentilation
```

получил такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Явных ошибок нету, а что именно ему, компьютеру, не нравится я не знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

`journalctl -b -u wentilation`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, читайте `journalctl -b -u wentilation` и не забывайте горизонтальный скроллинг, а то у вас все тексты обрезаны. Во-вторых, текущий каталог по умолчанию `/` и адрес `./program` скорее всего ссылается на файл `/program` которого просто-напросто не существует. Пропишите или абсолютный путь в скрипте, или `WorkingDirectory` в юнит-файле

Comment: Ну вон видите, journalctl вам пишет, что файла `./first_init` в рабочем каталоге всё-таки не существует. Перечитайте мой первый комментарий ещё раз и примените написанные мной рекомендации — они не бред, вы просто не даже не захотели попытаться понять мой комментарий.

Comment: Если вдруг вам всё ещё лень понимать мой комментарий — просто пропишите `WorkingDirectory=/kononov/initialization1` после строчки ExecStart. И не забудьте сделать `systemctl daemon-reload` после этого

Comment: @andreymal  извините, . Как прописать абсолютный путь в скрипте ?? Я прописывал `./kononov/initialization1/program` у вы пишет ошибку. Я пытался понять но у меня мало интелекта.

Comment: Абсолютный путь в линуксе всегда начинается с символа `/`. Точка в начале является вариантом относительного пути и указывает на текущий каталог, а текущий каталог может быть любым — и он не всегда совпадает с тем каталогом, в котором находится скрипт

Comment: @andreymal а как это на примере в скрипте реализовать ?  А то теория звучит так будто бы "гитлер в уши гвозди забивает". Просто я в башь прописал именно этот скрипт и при инициализации всё отрабатывает.

Comment: Не знаю, чего вас зациклило на абсолютном пути, прописать `WorkingDirectory=/kononov/initialization1` пробовали? Это должно решить проблему с несуществующим файлом даже при обычном `./program` (возможно, после этого появится какая-то новая проблема, но это нужно будет ещё раз journalctl читать)

Comment: @andreymal сработало оформляйте как ответ.(если в два дня не оформите то я оформлю)

Comment: @andreymal, автору надо разъяснить про `man realpath`.

Comment: ещё бы автору кто сказал про `stty cols 146` и что текст можно из путти копировать-вставить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Относительные пути работают только когда задан текущий каталог программы. На третьей картинке скрипт сообщает что не может найти программу. После завершается с кодом 127.

Чтоб скрипт знал где находится программа надо передать юниту рабочий каталог:

```
WorkingDirectory=/kononov/initialization1
```

Systemd сделает `cd` в этот каталог и оттуда выполнит скрипт.

Comment: шустрый, я аж не успел сам дать ответ :3

Comment: @timob256 хотел ответить, смотрю в коментариях уже есть. поэтому без рейтинга - "общий"

Comment: шустрый, 3 дня...)